# How to retrieve link location using preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

How to retrieve link location from following script using preg_match

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="www.example.com">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: if you are using CURL use

```
    <?php 
// ....
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION) 
    ?>
```

else

Location is in header "Location:http.."

try to get headers by [get_headers](http://tr.php.net/get_headers)
or parse this output by this pattern ,

```
$pattern = 'href=\"(?<url>[\"]+)\"'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you simply want to extract the url, from your html code? If so, you can do it like this:

```
preg_match('/object moved to <a href="(.+?)"> here/,$html_text,$match');
$url = $match[1];
```